# сохранение данных при обновлении страницы js

Tags: javascript

подскажите пожалуйста, а какими способами используя js можно сохранить данные при обновлении страницы??

Comment: можете, пожалуйста, пояснить, какие данные?

Comment: любые, просто данные в общем смысле, включая все возможные типы данных в js

Comment: как вариант cookie и localstorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если, например, товары корзины или другие не критичные данные пользователя, то в localStorage.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Например,
записать туда данные, можно так:

```
localStorage.setItem('eeeee', 1);
```

А посмотреть, что записали, вот так:

```
alert( localStorage.getItem('eeeee') );
```